# How to find the port number to be mentioned for master node url for creating a SparkContext in Amazon aws?

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, pyspark

I have `Spark 1.6` running on `Amazon AWS`. I am trying to run this code where I create a SparkContext by passing in the master node url but I am getting connection refused error. My current code is:

```
import fnmatch
import os
import sys
from os import system
from sys import argv
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext

def test(master_url):

    sc = SparkContext(master=master_url, appName='demo')

    sqlContext = SQLContext(sparkContext=sc)
    sqlContext.setConf('spark.sql.parquet.binaryAsString','true')

if __name__ == '__main__':

    master_url = 'spark://host_ip:7077'

    test(master_url)
```

When I run this code I get

```
WARN AppClient$ClientEndpoint: Failed to connect to master host_ip:7077
java.io.IOException: Failed to connect to /host_ip:7077
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your AWS security group that you've launched under is not configured to allow the appropriate connectivity.  The easiest way that I have found was to allow all ports to be open for any computer IN the security group.  You would open up all ports sourced FROM the security group.  Basically allowing any computer in your security group access to other computers in the same security group.
[image]

In my example, I launched under a security group named "launch-wizard-9" and went in and edited the security group to allow all traffic FROM that same group.

As long as there are no computers in your group that you don't want to have access then you should be good to go and this does not allow computers outside your group access to the computers in your group.

Alternatively you could go through the same exercise and open up each port TO THE GROUP or distinct computers in the group for each port Spark needs open.

I had the exact same error until I tweaked the security group to allow access among the machines.

**To find the port number:**

The port number of the master node is the default unless you specified otherwise when you started the master node. One thing I've gotten in the habit of doing is logging into the master node and doing a wget http://127.0.0.1:8080 and then vi or nano the index.html file to make sure everything looks correctly and then you can copy the exact network reference the master node is advertising along with the port number.

Hope that helps.